# What does "land tricks" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, verbs

I am not sure about the meaning of the word "land" in the following made-up sentence from a racing game:

> Land tricks to increase your speed and finish times.

The lexical meanings of the word ["land"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/land) do not seem to fit here.

In my opinion, the word land is being used as a verb here. However, it may imply the noun sense of "land" because the player has to pull off wheelies and flips which may involve landing.

Comment: I have always assumed that this is a reference to fishing. To "land" a fish means to catch it and get it out of the water on to the land.

Answer (score 4):

One of the meanings in the dictionary you cited, Merriam-Webster, *does* fit. It's definition 2e in the entry of [land](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/land) in the verb sense:

> to complete successfully by landing

An example is given as:

> the skater *landed* all her jumps

The jumps referred to in this example are most likely [those of a figure skater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_skating_jumps), though they may also be [skateboarding tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skateboarding_trick). In the video game, the tricks seem to resemble those of a [freestyle skiing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freestyle_skiing) competition, where skiers jump off a ramp, perform a trick in mid-air, and have to also *land* it in order to receive a good score.

In the game, all tricks may not be jumps, but if you "land tricks" that are, you are awarded a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

To "land" something means to successfully get or achieve something. For example:

> Alice landed a great job offer.

means that Alice got a great job offer.

Similarly, to "land" a trick means that you successfully did whatever it was: jump up, twirl the board around, and then return to the ground without falling.

I suspect that the origin of the term in reference to tricks is due to many tricks requiring you to leave the ground, but it wouldn't be surprising for someone succeeding at a ground-based trick to be described as having landed it.